# Inno Setup: Controls disappear (installer freezes) while installation is rolling back

Tags: inno-setup

When I confirm installation cancellation of the program, Inno Setup terminates or hides some of common and custom controls (labels, radiobuttons, etc.). Is it possible to keep them visible during WizardForm existence?

I use VCL Inno Styler to customize window and controls styling:

[image]
[image]

Here is what log file says:

```
 2016-05-16 13:50:01.225   Message box (Yes/No): Are you sure you want to close the installer? You won't be able to recover the data.
 2016-05-16 13:50:02.322   User chose Yes.
 2016-05-16 13:50:02.404   User canceled the installation process.
 2016-05-16 13:50:02.404   Rolling back changes.
 2016-05-16 13:50:02.408   Starting the uninstallation process.
 2016-05-16 13:50:02.408   Uninstallation process succeeded.
 2016-05-16 13:50:03.916   Deinitializing Setup.
 2016-05-16 13:50:11.176   Failed to remove temporary directory: C:\Users\AATASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\is-N7DAL.tmp
```

Comment: I assume you mean `OnCancelButtonClick`, right?

Comment: Also I assume that the controls are not hidden. They just probably fail to draw, because the installer stops processing windows messages (= stops responding). Why? Are you doing some rollback? What does the second screenshots actually show? What's happening there?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, OnCancelButtonClick.
What happens there: 
I'm trying to re-install (in testing purposes) program when it's instansce is running. And when I try to break installation by clicking close window button and confirm cancelation, most labels, checkboxes and radiobutton disappear, and after a couple of seconds window closes. 

The thing is that when controls disappear the window looks confusing

Comment: OK, but what's happening during those "couple of seconds"? Are you doing something or is Inno Setup itself doing something? What is it? Can you tell by inspecting the installer log?

Comment: OK, what the timestamps tell? Where's that "couple of seconds" gap?

Comment: That's just my observation. I think that it's just a time for rolling back changes and uninstallation, the main my disturbance is missing of controls during that time.

Comment: The messages in your comment are from the log. The log entries have timestamps. So it must be clear from the timestamps, what step took that long.

Comment: Please append the log to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "rollback" implementation in Inno Setup is far from perfect.

The Inno Setup does not process window message queue during the uninstallation. And it even explicitly freezes for 1500 ms, *"so that the user has time to read the "Rolling back changes" message"*.

As the message queue is not pumped, it's common in Windows that some controls (particularly those advanced) just disappear, because they do not process the "draw" requests. As you cannot make Inno Setup process the queue, you cannot really do anything about it.

Some partial solutions:

- Hide your advanced controls yourself and re-show the `WizardForm.StatusLabel` (which displays the *"Rolling back changes..."* message). The "labels" do not tend to disappear when message queue is not pumped.
- Hide whole window when the installer is cancelled using `WizardForm.Hide`.